# Do the decision tree regressors in random forests have different parameters?

Tags: random-forest, decision-tree, hyperparameters

Decision tree Regressors have several tunable parameters e.g criterion, max_depth, min_samples_leaf etc. Do theses trees have different parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by "do these trees have different parameters"?

Comment: I meant to say if the decision trees in random forest had different hyperperameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all have the same hyper parameter values  but the actual value of e.g depth might vary